# Contact form not detecting content of fields

Tags: php, forms, field, detect, contact-form

I have **very** limited knowledge of PHP so I used a contact form generator, but it does not function properly. The email does send successfully, but only the "email" and the "option" popups gets detected. Anything else returns empty.

Here is the code.

form.php

```
<?=$message?>

<form id="FormName" action="send.php" method="post" name="FormName">

<table width="448" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

<tr><td width = "150" align="right"><label for="EmailFrom">Your E-mail</label></td>

<td><input id="EmailFrom" type="text" name="EmailFrom" size="25"></td></tr>

<tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="text_field">text field</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input id="text_field" name="text_field" type="text" size="25" value="<?=$text_field?>" maxlength="255"></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="hello_world_1">Hello world 1</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input id="hello_world_1" name="hello_world_1" type="checkbox" value="Y"></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="hello_world_2">Hello world 2</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input id="hello_world_2" name="hello_world_2" type="checkbox" value="Y"></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="hello_world_3">Hello World 3</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input id="hello_world_3" name="hello_world_3" type="checkbox" value="Y"></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="text_area">text area</label></td>

<td valign="top"><textarea id="text_area" name="text_area" rows="4" cols="40"><?=$text_area?></textarea></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="popup">popup</label></td>

<td valign="top"><select id="popup" name="popup" size="1">

<option value="Option 1"<?php if($popup == "Option 1"){echo " selected";}?>>Option 1</option>

<option value="Option 2"<?php if($popup == "Option 2"){echo " selected";}?>>Option 2</option>

<option value="Option 3"<?php if($popup == "Option 3"){echo " selected";}?>>Option 3</option>

</select></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="date">date</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input id="date" name="<?=$date?>" type="text" size="25" value="<?=$date?>" maxlength="255"></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="hidden">hidden</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?=$hidden?>"></td></tr><tr><td width = "150" align="right" valign="top"><label for="image">image</label></td>

<td valign="top"><input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?=$hidden?>"></td></tr><tr>

<td width="150"></td>

<td>

<input type="submit" name="submitButtonName" value="Send E-mail"></td>



</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

send.php

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = $_POST['EmailFrom'];

$text_field = trim($_POST['text_field']);

$hello_world_1 = trim($_POST['hello_world_1']);

$hello_world_2 = trim($_POST['hello_world_2']);

$hello_world_3 = trim($_POST['hello_world_3']);

$text_area = trim($_POST['text_area']);

$popup = trim($_POST['popup']);

$date = trim($_POST['date']);

$hidden = trim($_POST['hidden']);

$image = trim($_POST['image']);



$EmailTo = "nomail@nomail.com";

$Subject = ""; /// Add a subject



$validationOK=true;

if (trim($EmailFrom)=="") $validationOK=false;

if (!$validationOK) {

  echo "Error! E-mail was not sent. Please check you code.";

  exit;

}





$Body = "";

$Body .= "text field:\n$textfield\n\n";

$Body .= "Hello world 1:\n$helloworld1\n\n";

$Body .= "Hello world 2:\n$helloworld2\n\n";

$Body .= "Hello World 3:\n$helloworld3\n\n";

$Body .= "text area:\n$textarea\n\n";

$Body .= "popup:\n$popup\n\n";

$Body .= "date:\n$date\n\n";

$Body .= "hidden:\n$hidden\n\n";

$Body .= "image:\n$image\n\n";



if($Subject == NULL) {$Subject = "From $EmailFrom";}

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");



if ($success){ echo "Success! Your e-mail was sent!";}

else{  echo "Error! Your e-mail was not sent!";}

?>
```

Why does it not function? Also, if you could recommend a working php form generator, that would be very helpful. I require both checkbox and popup/radiobutton.

Comment: try this http://www.jotform.com/ you will have to include a javascript file, and all the job will be done by their side :)

Comment: It appears that the site you suggested does not provide the local code, its an embedment type of service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are named like "$text_field" (with underscore) but when appending to $Body you do not use the underscores, e.g. "$textfield". Thus the variable "$textfield" is not even set, meaning empty.

Comment: Then why does the text_area return empty aswell?

Comment: text_area is mispelled too (textarea) in $Body

Comment: Oh I see, so I just adjust the $body variables to match with the rest, as they are missing the underscore? My bad, cheers for the help!